# How to get list of methods in a C# project that is referenced to another project(dll reference)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dll

I have two separate C# projects,

1. A C# project is only used as a dll reference
2. A C# project with 1st project as dll reference.

Now I need to clean up the old methods of 1st project which is used as a dll reference.

How can I find the functions/ methods that I am actively using/ calling from the 2nd to 1st project.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: As rene says recommendation questions are off topic. However I think the question can stand without that so I have edited that part away. There may be ways to do it that fit this site. I wouldn't be at all surprised if there was a way to do it with Roslyn.

Comment: thanks guys. i'm sorry about that. Any solutions. Because it is hard to find it manually. :(

Answer (score 1):

I would comment out the Using reference to Project 1, then see which lines generate compile errors. That's where the references are used.

If you use Visual Studio, you can find them all if you install Resharper:

Expand the References and choose Find code Dependent on Module

Comment: Yep, this is a great idea and i tried that too. But it will eat my whole day of work. So trying for another solution. I know you will think i'm lazy. :)

Comment: No, lazy is smart!

Comment: Resharper in Visual Studio can help.